# How do I properly iterate through a mysqli_fetch_array (procedural)?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have what I thought would be a simple process updating old "mysql" code to "mysqli."  In a number of places there was code that iterated through a multi-dimensional array to get the values.  I'm trying to make a similar loop and use either mysqli_fetch_array or mysqli_fetch_all and am just banging my head against a wall.  Either the process fails (hang) or else it doesn't return any values.  I have looked all over the web and found various examples, none of which have quite worked...often they're not for procedural method (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026979/how-do-iterate-the-result-of-mysqli-fetch-array).

I currently have:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM mp WHERE email='$email'";

//connect to database    
require("../dbinfo.php");
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);                 

$result2=@mysqli_query($con, $query2);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH);
@mysqli_close($con);  //question...does this need to come later, after num_rows?


$num2=0;
$num2=@mysqli_num_rows($result2);


$a=0;
while ($a < $num2)
        {
//cycle through to get info...this comes up blank, when it should have 3 sets of values.
            $var1=$array[$a]["column"];
            $var2=$array[$a]["id"];
            echo "Column: ".$var1." and ID: ".$var2;
}
```

I've seen a lot of answers that essentially say "Use PDO" or "why use procedural?  Object oriented is the way to go" but I'm really not looking to do a different style.  It would be great to just know what's causing the above to fail.  I can't be too far off, right?  Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You'll want to put the mysqli_close at the bottom of the page after all mysqli calls. You don't want to close the connection before you finish all those functions.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection, unless you perform checks on the `$email` variable.

Comment: Yes, thank you...there's lots of additional code that verifies.  I'm not worried about SQL Injection.  But @Rasclatt , I've tried moving the mysqli_close to the end and it still isn't working.  I realized that it's failing for some reason to pull out any values in the $var1, $var2 section.  The mysqli_num_rows part works, I'm getting (in this case) 3 iterations.  But all I see is "Column: and ID:" repeated three times.  Is the [$a] part incorrectly written?  Should it be $array($a, "column") or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should move `@mysqli_close($con);` to a point where you won't call any more `mysqli`-functions (basically, the bottom).

Secondly, you should look up the `mysqli_fetch_array()`-function in the PHP-manual:

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or
>   NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.

So it returns an array that corresponds to **one** row, not all rows, meaning that the statement `$array[$a]["column"];` doesn't make much sense (I know you're trying to do what the other answer said, but you haven't included the appropriate code to do so [it's provided further down in that answer]). So instead, I recommend using the normal way: Try removing `$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH)`, and add this instead of your `while`-loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo "Column: " . $row["column"] . " and ID: " . $row["ID"];
}
```

Since `mysqli_fetch_array()` changes the result-object, you will get a different result for every loop, meaning that `$row` will consist of different values. Every different value will be a different row in the database, with the columns as the array keys, and the values as the array values. However, since you're using `MYSQLI_BOTH`, you can also access a value by using the column-number as the array key. If you don't need this, I suggest changing it to `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.

This also means that you can completely remove the `$num2`-variable, and the `$a`-variable. If you want to use the method you're using now, you need to use the second code provided in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026979/how-do-iterate-the-result-of-mysqli-fetch-array) before the `while`-loop. Although note that you need to increase the variable `$a` with 1 for every loop too, which your current code won't do. Basically, you would need to change it to:

```
$var1=$array[$a]["column"];
$var2=$array[$a++]["id"]; //the variable $a is increased after $var2 is assigned
echo "Column: ".$var1." and ID: ".$var2;
```

Although this code is a lot more complicated if you're just going to print the variables... Instead of just printing them, you're assigning them to an array, and later printing them again, which requires 2 loops instead of one. Personally, I would recommend changing the entire code as follows:

```
//connect to database    
require("../dbinfo.php");

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);                 
$result2 = @mysqli_query($con, $query2);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo "Column: " . $row["column"] . " and ID: " . $row["ID"];
}

@mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Jesus, this is a great answer.  Thank you.  I am FINALLY starting to understand this...didn't quite get the concept of how mysqli_fetch_array would change automatically each iteration.  However, I'm finding that when I do it this way, it only runs 2 times, when it SHOULD run 3.  There are 3 lines in the array that should be being pulled out...why would it be only seeing 2 of them?

Comment: (I'm basing this on the num_rows value = 3.)

Comment: Annnd, you can ignore that last bit.  I had commented out something and forgotten that I needed it.  IT'S WORKING FINE NOW.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @user1149499 Glad to hear! If you're curious about how the `while`-loop works: the reason it changes has to do with pointers - basically, `mysqli_fetch_array()` both returns the current row as an array AND increases the "row-pointer" so it points to the next row. This means that when calling it again, you will refer to the second row, and increase the pointer to the third row, and so on. When it runs out of rows, it will return `NULL` instead, meaning that the condition in the `while` loop will return false, and the loop will break. For every loop, `$row` will contain a different row.

Comment: With all stated above: The reason it changes on each iteration has to do with the modification of the `$result2` object (as explained above), meaning that it "automatically" will change on each iteration (had to make another comment; last one would have been too long).

Comment: Thank you for the additional info!  It's making more sense now.  Though now (in a different section of code) I'm wondering how I do 2 different $results sets in the same loop.  I used to do "num_rows" and then a line like $name = $num($result1, $a, "name"); $quantity = $num($result2, $a, "quantity"); so that one loop would pull from 2 different queries and combine them.  It seems like to do that now I'd need to have two different mysqli_fetch_array lines WITHIN a larger loop?  Or do I nest?  Or do I maybe fetch a single row?  Sorry to pester...and thank you again for your time!

Comment: Do you mean looping through 2 `$result` variables in the same loop? In that case, you can use `while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_BOTH) && $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH))` if you want the loop to end when one result set is finished, or `while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_BOTH) || $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_BOTH))` when both have finished. Not sure if I'm misunderstanding you though.

Comment: Okay!  Yes, the first example is what I was thinking of!  Thank you!